# How to use vnc:// links in windows and tightvnc

Tags: vnc, url, protocol-handler

I woulk like to register vnc:// protocol to launch tightvnc link directly from the browser.

Link example:
vlc://192.168.0.1

Right now I wrote in the registry this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VNC]
@="URL:vnc"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VNC\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VNC\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VNC\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\TightVNC\\tvnviewer.exe\" \"-host=%1\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\VNC]
@="URL:vnc"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\VNC\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\VNC\shell\open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\VNC\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\TightVNC\\tvnviewer.exe\" \"-host=%1\""
```

And if I browse vlc://192.168.0.1

TightVNC reply with this error:

```
Connection parameters (host, port, socket, gates) is empty
```

Do you what I'm missing?